# Is there any way to reuse IntelliJ ui components such as com.intellij.ui.components.JBScrollPane?

Tags: intellij-idea

When calling new `JScrollPane`, I was prompted to use a `JBScrollPane`.

```
com.intellij.ui.components.JBScrollPane
```

But when I do `import com.intellij.ui.components.JBScrollPane`, the compilation triggered an error.

```
error: cannot find symbol
import com.intellij.ui.components.JBScrollPane;
```

I tried adding this repository [artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intellij), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inspection is supposed to be shown only in the code of IntelliJ itself and IntelliJ plugins; if you saw it in a regular Swing project, it's a bug.

IntelliJ components can be adapted to be used outside of IntelliJ, but they are not packaged and published in a way that makes it easy.